# How to show Current Date Time when the button clicked in SQLlite Flutter?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

[This is My App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8MaV.jpg)

I want to add a new column contain the current date when add new name, this is my code any help?
this class to add the name

```
class Employee {
  int id;
  String name;

  Employee(this.id, this.name);

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = <String, dynamic>{
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
    };
    return map;
  }

  Employee.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    id = map['id'];
    name = map['name'];
  }
}
```

and here is the database i use to store the name and show the delete button how can i add a new column here contain the current date time when adding new name?

**strong text**

```
Future<List<Employee>> employees;
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  String name;
  int curUserId;

  final formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var dbHelper;
  bool isUpdating;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dbHelper = DBHelper();
    isUpdating = false;
    refreshList();
  }

  refreshList() {
    setState(() {
      employees = dbHelper.getEmployees();
    });
  }

  clearName() {
    controller.text = '';
  }

  validate() {
    if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      formKey.currentState.save();
      if (isUpdating) {
        Employee e = Employee(curUserId, name);
        dbHelper.update(e);
        setState(() {
          isUpdating = false;
        });
      } else {
        Employee e = Employee(null, name);
        dbHelper.save(e);
      }
      clearName();
      refreshList();
    }
  }

  form() {
    return Form(
      key: formKey,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              controller: controller,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Name'),
              validator: (val) => val.length == 0 ? 'Enter Name' : null,
              onSaved: (val) => name = val,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: validate,
                  child: Text(isUpdating ? 'UPDATE' : 'ADD'),
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      isUpdating = false;
                    });
                    clearName();
                  },
                  child: Text('CANCEL'),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  SingleChildScrollView dataTable(List<Employee> employees) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      child: DataTable(
        columns: [
          DataColumn(
            label: Text('NAME'),
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text('DELETE'),
          ),
        //  DataColumn(label: Text("")'null')

        ],
        rows: employees
            .map(
              (employee) => DataRow(cells: [
                    DataCell(
                      Text(employee.name),
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          isUpdating = true;
                          curUserId = employee.id;
                        });
                        controller.text = employee.name;
                      },
                    ),
                    DataCell(IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                      onPressed: () {
                        dbHelper.delete(employee.id);
                        refreshList();
                      },
                    )),
                  ]),
            )
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }

  list() {
    return Expanded(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: employees,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return dataTable(snapshot.data);
          }

          if (null == snapshot.data || snapshot.data.length == 0) {
            return Text("No Data Found");
          }

          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(

      title: new Text('Stay_Safe'),
      centerTitle: true
      ),
      body: new Container(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
          children: <Widget>[
            form(),
            list(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add DateTime to Employee model:

```
class Employee {
  int id;
  String name;
  DateTime dateTime;

  Employee(this.id, this.name, this.dateTime);

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    map['id'] = this.id;
    map['name'] = this.name;
    map['dateTime'] = dateTime != null ? this.dateTime.toIso8601String() : '';
    return map;
  }

  Employee.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    id = map['id'];
    name = map['name'];
    dateTime = map['dateTime'] != null? DateTime.parse(map['dateTime']): null;
  }
}
```

DateTime.now() returns current DateTime of user.We will pass this whenever user is updating or adding new data.We will create another data column and cell for showing time.The datetime needs to be converted to presentable string so we will use our custom function getFormattedDate and lastly show it in Text widget.

```
Future<List<Employee>> employees;
TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
String name;
int curUserId;

final formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
var dbHelper;
bool isUpdating;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  dbHelper = DBHelper();
  isUpdating = false;
  refreshList();
}

refreshList() {
  setState(() {
    employees = dbHelper.getEmployees();
  });
}

clearName() {
  controller.text = '';
}

validate() {
  if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
    formKey.currentState.save();
    if (isUpdating) {
      Employee e = Employee(curUserId, name,DateTime.now());
      dbHelper.update(e);
      setState(() {
        isUpdating = false;
      });
    } else {
      Employee e = Employee(null, name,DateTime.now());
      dbHelper.save(e);
    }
    clearName();
    refreshList();
  }
}

form() {
  return Form(
    key: formKey,
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            controller: controller,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Name'),
            validator: (val) => val.length == 0 ? 'Enter Name' : null,
            onSaved: (val) => name = val,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: validate,
                child: Text(isUpdating ? 'UPDATE' : 'ADD'),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    isUpdating = false;
                  });
                  clearName();
                },
                child: Text('CANCEL'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}

SingleChildScrollView dataTable(List<Employee> employees) {
  return SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    child: DataTable(
      columns: [
        DataColumn(
          label: Text('NAME'),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text('DELETE'),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text('DATE'),
        ),
        //  DataColumn(label: Text("")'null')

      ],
      rows: employees
          .map(
            (employee) => DataRow(cells: [
          DataCell(
            Text(employee.name),
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                isUpdating = true;
                curUserId = employee.id;
              });
              controller.text = employee.name;
            },
          ),
          DataCell(IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
            onPressed: () {
              dbHelper.delete(employee.id);
              refreshList();
            },
          )),
              DataCell(

                Text(((DateTime date) =>
                "${date.hour % 12}:${date.minute} ${date.hour > 12
                    ? 'PM'
                    : 'AM'}")(
                    employee.dateTime) + ' ${getFormattedDate(employee.dateTime.toIso8601String())}'),
                onTap: () {
                  //Any action
                },
              ),
        ]),
      )
          .toList(),
    ),
  );
}

list() {
  return Expanded(
    child: FutureBuilder(
      future: employees,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return dataTable(snapshot.data);
        }

        if (null == snapshot.data || snapshot.data.length == 0) {
          return Text("No Data Found");
        }

        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    ),
  );
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(

        title: new Text('Stay_Safe'),
        centerTitle: true
    ),
    body: new Container(
      child: new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
        children: <Widget>[
          form(),
          list(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}


String getFormattedDate(String date) {
  var d = DateTime.parse(date);
  return   [
    "Jan",
    "Feb",
    "Mar",
    "Apr",
    "May",
    "Jun",
    "Jul",
    "Aug",
    "Sep",
    "Oct",
    "Nov",
    "Dec"
  ][d.month - 1] +
      " " +   d.day.toString() +
      "," +
      d.year.toString();
}
```

Comment: No Errors but when i enter the data in the TextFiled and click add nothing happen i think the problem in the ontap function you didn't write it !